# How to decompress without any extraction a .tar.xz file into .tar file?

Tags: command-line, tar

I have -

`file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt`, `file4.txt`, `file5.txt`

Now, I do -

```
tar -cvf archive.tar file[1-5].txt
```

Next, I do

```
xz archive.tar
```

and I get `archive.tar.xz`

Now, How can I get back my `archive.tar` from `archive.tar.xz`?

for `gzip` algorithm the command is `gunzip`

for `bzip2` algorithm the command is `bunzip2`

Is there any similar command for `xz` algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. See `man xz`:

```
NAME
       xz,  unxz, xzcat, lzma, unlzma, lzcat - Compress or decompress .xz and
       .lzma files

SYNOPSIS
       xz [option...]  [file...]

COMMAND ALIASES
       unxz is equivalent to xz --decompress.
       xzcat is equivalent to xz --decompress --stdout.
       lzma is equivalent to xz --format=lzma.
       unlzma is equivalent to xz --format=lzma --decompress.
       lzcat is equivalent to xz --format=lzma --decompress --stdout.

[. . .]
```

So you just want `unxz archive.tar.xz` or `xz --decompress archive.tar.xz`.

Note that `tar` can do all this for you, there's no reason to first create a tar archive and then compress it, you can create it compressed:

```
tar -cJvf archive.tar file[1-5].txt
```

That will produce `archive.tar.xz`. From `man tar`:

```
       -J, --xz
              Filter the archive through xz(1).
```

You can then decompress in one step to get the original files back with:

```
tar -xJvf archive.tar.xz
```